# Include dataframe linear optimization in r

Tags: integer-programming, r

For a linear optimization problem I want to include a dataframe (d_ij) which has binary variables,
1 if customer i is located within the assignable distance of facility j, 0 otherwise. So unless d_ij = 1, the customer cannot be assigned to a facility.
To create the model, I have introduced a binary variable X_ij (for customers) and Y_j (for the facilities)

The dataframe is constructed as follows:

```
#creating distance function
e <- function(i, j) {
  customer <- data[i, ]
  facility <- facility_locations[j, ]
  (sqrt((customer$x - facility$x)^2 + (customer$y - facility$y)^2))
}


#with ifelse function, we model if the distance between consumer and facility is smaller than z =1, 0 otherwise

deltaframe <- data.frame(
  customer=data$ID,
  "j1" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==1)<z,1,0),
  "j2" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==2)<z,1,0),
  "j3" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==3)<z,1,0),
  "j4" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==4)<z,1,0),
  "j5" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==5)<z,1,0),
  "j6" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==6)<z,1,0),
  "j7" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==7)<z,1,0),
  "j8" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==8)<z,1,0),
  "j9" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==9)<z,1,0),
  "j10" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==10)<z,1,0),
  "j11" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==11)<z,1,0),
  "j12" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==12)<z,1,0),
  "j13" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==13)<z,1,0),
  "j14" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==14)<z,1,0),
  "j15" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==15)<z,1,0),
  "j16" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==16)<z,1,0),
  "j17" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==17)<z,1,0),
  "j18" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==18)<z,1,0),
  "j19" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==19)<z,1,0),
  "j20" =ifelse(e(data$ID, facility_locations$ID==20)<z,1,0)
)
```

Here z is a parameter, set to be the maximum distance a customer is willing to travel.

The constraint I try to model is
$x_{ij} <= d_{ij} * y_j $  for all i and for all j

However, I do not know how to include this in r

Comment: What R package are you using to build the model?

Comment: Can you please put a sample of the data frame ```data```? And is ```z``` a vector?

Answer (score 3):

MILP modelling in R is not as advanced or convenient as it is in Python or Julia. Few exceptions I know about are [ROI](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/roi/) and [ompr](https://github.com/dirkschumacher/ompr) packages. ompr seems to be actively maintained thanks to Dirk Schumacher.

edit: [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) is a more comprehensive list.

If you are just looking for presenting solutions or solving in a purely functional/algebraic way you might want to check [plyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) package for apply-style implementations such as mdply, ddply or ldply. purrr package is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.  You'll need to learn the basics of `ompr`, which is an awesome package.  I use it regularly, including with Gurobi for large-scale optimizations.

https://towardsdatascience.com/supply-chain-design-using-r-unconstrained-warehouse-customer-alignment-9ec11c1e4345

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm working in ompr indeed and made it work through introducing a function, which i later include in a constraint in the model. 
```delta <- function (i,j){ ifelse(e(i,j)<=z,1,0)
}```

Comment: OK.  You could also just make a static matrix of 1 and 0, 1 representing if the pairing is allowed, 0 if not.  then x[i,j] <= my_static_matrix[i,j] in the constraints